# What exactly does the call operator in PowerShell do?

Tags: powershell, process, console-application

I have a powershell script that runs some executable using call operator. Something like this:

```
$executable = 'c:\dev\test.exe'
& $executable | Out-Host
Write-Host 'done'
```

That `test.exe` in turn runs another programs (`server.exe`) and communicates with it over TCP/IP (this program requires administrative privileges and because of that my powershell script is run as admin), also it runs trivial batch script (which runs and terminates in 1 second). Once started, `server.exe` runs until terminated by `test.exe`. All programs involved are console applications. Another fact probably worth noting is that since `server.exe` requires admin privileges it runs in separate console window than `test.exe`.

Sometimes  `test.exe` does not terminate `server.exe` (sometimes due to crash, sometimes due to bugs in it). When this happens, after `test.exe` termination execution does not return to powershell script (I don't see 'done' being printed). If I terminate `server.exe` manually, I immediately see 'done' in the powershell console. Why is this happening? Why powershell waits for process to terminate which it had not started and which does not even run in the same console?

In my investigation attempts I tried to reproduce the issue with less amount of code involved I created `test2.exe` which simply runs `server.exe` (exactly the same way, I have access to `test.exe` sources) and terminates. Now when I run the same powershell script but with `test2.exe` as `$executable`, I see exactly what I expected to see initially: `server.exe` starts in separate window, then 'done' is printed in powershell window (and powershell script terminates) while `server.exe` still runs.

I watched Process Explorer while `test.exe` run and I am sure no other process besides `server.exe` are running after `test.exe` termination.

I failed to find any in-depth explanation what `&` operator does and what it waits for, maybe you have some ideas?

**Update:** Instead of running with call operator I tried `Start-Process`:

```
$executable = 'c:\dev\test.exe'
Start-Process $executable -Wait
Write-Host 'done'
```

Now `test.exe` runs in it's own console, terminates and powershell still waits for `server.exe` to finish.

Also I tried to run the batch script:

```
c:\dev\test.exe
echo done
```

and it works fine: as soon as `test.exe` terminates 'done' is printed to console and batch file stops (`server.exe` is still running).

**Another update:** changed script to do the following:

```
$executable = 'c:\dev\test.exe'
$proc = Start-Process $executable -PassThru
do {
   Get-Process -Id $proc.Id
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
} while ($true)
```

I am getting the regular `Get-Process` output few times while `test.exe` is running then (after `test.exe` terminates) it starts producing "Cannot find process with the process identifier 3028" errors. So I probably can go this way.

Another thing I tried was:

```
$env:PATH += ';c:\dev\;'
test.exe
Write-Host 'done'
```

Still, no luck: `test.exe` terminates, powershell still waits for `server.exe` to terminate.

Tried the job approach, too:

```
$job = Start-Job {& 'c:\dev\test.exe'}
do
{
    $job
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
} while ($job.JobStateInfo.State -eq [System.Management.Automation.JobState]::Running)

Receive-Job $job
```

It never quits unless I terminate `server.exe`.

Comment: I'm probably in over my head here with the likes of Keith Hill responding to you, but have you considered running the executable as a job? That way even if it isn't letting PS know that it has terminated for some reason you should be able to run get-process and check if it's running, then act accordingly.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, how do I run executable as a job? `Start-Job` can only run powershell scripts as far as I understand.

Comment: Yes, jobs are for scripts, but that just means you put curly braces around your command and treat it as a script block. `$myjob = Start-job {& test.exe}`

Answer (score 6):

The call operator `&` simply attempts invoke the named command (application, script, function, cmdlet) following it, passing any additional arguments to the command.  In addition, `&` executes the command in a new scope whereas the `.` executes the command in the current scope.  When executing an application (exe) I don't think it matters that you execute in a new scope.  The exe can't impact scoped variables in PowerShell.

WRT the test.exe behavior, PowerShell won't return control to the script until a console exe finishes.  Test.exe and test2.exe are both console subsystem exes right?  PowerShell behaves differently with Windows subsystem exes.  It launches them and returns immediately unless you use a trick like this `notepad.exe | Out-Null`.

Comment: Yes, both test.exe and test2.exe are console subsystem executables. And I verified that test.exe terminates, but for some reason powershell waits for server.exe to terminate.

Comment: How it invokes executable? `CreateProcess` or `ShellExecute` or something else? what exactly it waits for after spawning process?

Comment: From inspecting the code, it looks like it would use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() if the extension is an executable.  So in that case I'm pretty sure it isn't using `ShellExecute`.  Also, in the case of console apps it doesn't just launch the app.  PowerShell captures the apps stdout/stderr IO. This allows the app to output text to the PowerShell console. The consequence is that PowerShell waits until the console app exits before proceeding to the next command.

Comment: Interesting, so the behavior is different depending on what [Windows subsystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem?view=msvc-170) the executable was linked against? Why? And why does `| Out-Null` affect that behavior? Seems like there's a lot going on under the hood here that has yet to be explained.